# setCustomAnimations(R.anim.s lide_up_info,0,0,R.anim.slide_down_info) works only for one side animation

Tags: android

I want to slide a fragment from bottom to up and then back from top to bottom. But bottom to up animation is working fine on clicking a button. How to slide back from top to bottom on pressing same button again?
    Code is here:

```
Fragment sheet = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag");
FragmentTransaction ft =     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.s    lide_up_info,0,0,R.anim.slide_down_info).show(sheet);
ft.addToBackStack("dialer");
ft.commit();

XML are:
slide_down_info.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

And slide_up_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```